# Why does eclipse hide my jni folder in Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse

Every now and then eclipse hides folders for me without no obvious reason. The most common is that the jni-folder is not visible in Project Explorer view, nor any of the other views. Also the folders cannot be viewed in any other view in eclipse.

A way to go around this is to rename the folder on the file system, refresh the folder in eclipse, and rename the folder back inside eclipse, but i don't find this a good solution. Why does eclipse hide folders in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this addresses your problem, but one mechanism that Eclipse uses to show/hide folders is the "Filters" menu.

In the top right corner of the Project Explorer there is a down arrow (triangle). Click this and go to "Customize view". If the folder you mention matches any of the boxes that are checked under the "Filter" tab, you can uncheck these and the folder will be visible.

Comment: Yes, I have been elaborating with that for a while, but even after all filters were removed the jni folder did not appear.